# Introduce middleware-like implementation for a singleton class member

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a singleton Communication class which has numerous methods. I want to enforce that whenever any method of that class is called, a check is made to see if the server is up, and if not, then start it.

It seems a lot like middleware we implement in case of REST servers, but this one is on the client side.

How should I approach a problem like this?  Is there a cleaner way around calling a check method in every case explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean with "cleaner way around"? How to build a class that does this for you?

Comment: yes, exactly. I need a way to get this functionality. I feel you are suggesting a wrapper of some kind.

Comment: Yes, However: there are numerous ways to archive the same. Either a full-class-wrapper, some simple method that gets called like this `server.InvokeWithCheck(() => server.APIEndpoint())` or some special runtime generated stuff (only possible with clean interfacing)

Comment: yup, thanks. That would work.

Comment: You can let the wrapper be generated via a T4 Template btw.

Answer (score 0):

You write that the code in the singleton is running on the client and you want to verify if the server is up-and-running and otherwise start the server. Why is it necessary for the client to spin up the server?

Wouldn’t it be a good idea to leave the responsibility of starting the server to another service? Perhaps it’s a good idea to have the method fail with a ServerNotRunning exception for instance. With a special wrapper you can start the server from there.

This will ensure the Communications only does what it should do, communicate with the server.

Comment: server is a named pipe server running on the same machine. So I would prefer not to include another service just to look after the server. But I think you mean that the exception handler can also be abstracted to restart the server. Thanks.

Comment: That was indeed what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in design here. You will face several issues:
1) Client side will be tightly coupled to the server
2) There can be many servers in future

I propose you to have third component. This component task will be to ensure that service/server is up and running. Actually there are already existing implementations that do that like `pm2` for example

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of context, I am implementing a named pipe call forwarding to support x86 clients in my x64 system. I suppose only one server per machine with multiple possible clients. 
So Tight coupling and multiple servers is not an issue. I just wanted not to write a lot of repetitive code.